# basic node.js html file serving not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs')

http.createServer(function(req, res){
    fs.readFile('./samplehtml.html',function(err,data){
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
    
}).listen(7000);
```

when i run the above code it shows SITE CANNOT BE REACHED  in browser.
The following error is shown

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received undefined
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:722:11)
    at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:687:15)
    at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Users\riyab\OneDrive\Desktop\node\main.js:7:13)
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:282:13) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
```

Comment: Is your HTML file named `samplehtml.html`? This error happens when the `fs` module can't find the file. Make sure `samplehtml.html` is in the right path (in the same directory as where your js file is executed).

Comment: Why dont you evaluate what your `err` arugment is? As posted by many other people here, you have a problem with reading the content of the html file. *NEVER* Ignore a error or do not evalute a error argument. Thats bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `fs.readFile()`, you must check for errors. It is very likely that the file `./samplehtml.html` doesn't exist (probably, because the path is not relative to the location of the `.js` script, as you might expect).

Try this:

```js
const path = require("path");
...
fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "./samplehtml.html"), (err, data) => {
...
```